# Computing all intersection points between Voronoi diagram and Convex Hull

Tags: python, scipy, intersection, convex-hull, voronoi

I am looking for an efficient way to calculate all the intersection points between the Voronoi diagram and the convex hull of the sites (using scipy.spatial). Does something like this exist using scipy or numpy, or must I check for each edge of the Voronoi diagram if it intersects any edge of the convex hull?